# SQL query to get outstanding balance per row from 2 tables for common ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

MySQL VERSION > 5.7
I am using MySQL 8 right now but I don't see any difference from version effect.

Table-1 : invoice_master

```
ID           amount      status      type               optional_reference_ID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
inv_id_1        150      Open        Invoice            NULL
inv_id_2        200      Open        Invoice            NULL
inv_id_3        500      Open        Invoice            NULL
inv_id_4        -50      Open        Credit_Note        inv_id_1
inv_id_5        200      Closed      Invoice            NULL
inv_id_6         70      Open        Debit_Note         inv_id_2
```

NOTE : credit or debit will have ref_ID always to sum them for actual payable amount for any invoice

Table-2 : payment_master

```
ID          ref_invoice_ID    amount      status
-------------------------------------------------------
pmt_id_1          inv_id_1       100      Collected
pmt_id_2          inv_id_2       200      Confirmed
pmt_id_3          inv_id_3       350      Failed
pmt_id_4          inv_id_3       350      Initiated
pmt_id_5          inv_id_3        20      Initiated
```

I want the output look like following

Note : SELECT only WHERE status = 'Open'
so, `inv_id_5` will be excluded in output directly without any calculation because it's status is 'Closed'
Also Failed payments will be discarded from any calculations

```
ID           amount      Outstanding_amount
------------------------------------------------------------
inv_id_1        150                       0
inv_id_2        200                      70
inv_id_3        500                     130
inv_id_6         70                      70
```

Equation for Outstanding is :

```
Outstanding = Invoice_amount + Credit/Debit_Note 
-- payment associated for the current Invoice_id
```

So,

Example - 1 (For inv_id_1)

```
-----------example for inv_id_1   START-----------
0 (outstanding) = 150 (invoice_master.amount for inv_id_1) + any other entry with same reference id `inv_id_1` (-50) - SUM of {payments with the ref_ID `inv_id_1`} (100)

0 = 150 + (-50) - 100
-----------example for inv_id_1   END-----------
```

Example - 2 (For inv_id_2)

```
-----------example for inv_id_2   START-----------
70 (outstanding) = 200 (invoice_master.amount for inv_id_2) + any other entry with same reference id `inv_id_2` (70) -  SUM of {payments with the ref_ID `inv_id_2`} (200)

70 = 200 + (70) - 200
-----------example for inv_id_2   END-----------
```

Can I get a query to do this? I am stuck.

Thanks you in advance for help.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on (NB it's always useful to publish this when posting)

Comment: 3 tables I see only 2?

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03784600fed2c3a3698f762cde80d244). The rest cannot be created now because the explanations are too unclear.

Comment: I have changes title. Actually tables are 3 but I need help with only 2 as another 3rd will also work same as the procedure displayed here.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi If 3rd table not needed for the question - remove it from question text.

Comment: A query to do what?  I don't figure out what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Query to get Outstanding amount as displayed in Example with explanation from equation given.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  t1.ID, t1.amount as orig_invoice_amt, t2.amount as crdr_amt,
        sum(t1.amount + t2.amount) as net_invoice_amt, sum(t1.amount + t2.amount - t3.amount) as outstanding
    from  invoice_master t1
    LEFT JOIN  invoice_master t2  ON t2.optional_reference_ID = t1.ID
    INNER JOIN  payment_master t3  ON t1.ID = t3.ref_invoice_ID
    WHERE  t3.status != "Failed"
      AND  t2.optional_reference_ID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY  t2.optional_reference_ID
UNION  ALL 
select  t1.ID, t1.amount as orig_invoice_amt, t2.amount as crdr_amt,
        sum(t1.amount + t2.amount) as net_invoice_amt, t1.amount as outstanding
    from  invoice_master t1
    LEFT JOIN  invoice_master t2  ON t2.optional_reference_ID = t1.ID
    WHERE  t1.type = "Debit_Note"
      AND  t2.optional_reference_ID IS NULL
    GROUP BY  t2.optional_reference_ID
UNION  ALL 
SELECT  iQuery.ID, iQuery.orig_invoice_amt as orig_invoice_amt,
        iQuery.crdr_amt as crdr_amt, iQuery.net_invoice_amt as net_invoice_amt,
        SUM(iQuery.orig_invoice_amt - iQuery.crdr_amt) as outstanding
    from  
    (
        SELECT  t1.ID as ID, t1.amount as orig_invoice_amt, SUM(t3.amount) as crdr_amt,
                NULL as net_invoice_amt, NULL as outstanding
            from  invoice_master t1
            INNER JOIN  payment_master t3  ON t1.ID = t3.ref_invoice_ID
            where  t1.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT  t2.optional_reference_ID
                    from  invoice_master t2
                    where  t2.optional_reference_ID is NOT NULL
                          )
              AND  t1.optional_reference_ID is NULL
              AND  t1.status != "Closed"
              AND  t3.status != "Failed"
            GROUP BY  t1.ID
    ) as iQuery
```

Comment: Now, explain how it solves the Op's problem, and why the UNIONs, and the LEFTs.